# Jenkins `if (sh '...')`

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How can I make Jenkins run a `sh` command inside of a conditional? I'd like it to abort its execution if it pulls a git commit that begins with 'WIP'.

What I envision is:

```
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    // some steps ...
    script {
      if (sh "git log -1 --pretty='format:%B' | grep -q ^WIP") {
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        return
      }
    }
    // more steps ...
  }
}
```

...but my pipeline complains "expecting ')', found 'git log -1 --pretty='format:%B' | grep -q ^WIP'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use `sh` step does not return any output, and `sh(command)` does not return any output. You need to use `sh(script: command, returnStdout: true)` to get the output of the shell command. Also, you need to remove `-q` param from `grep` to get any output returned to the console.

```groovy
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    // some steps ...
    script {
      if (sh(script:"git log -1 --pretty='format:%B' | grep ^WIP", returnStdout: true).trim()) {
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        return
      }
    }
    // more steps ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue of the Groovy parser. Simply enclose arguments in parenthesis:

```
if (sh("git log -1 --pretty='format:%B' | grep -q ^WIP"))
```